# How to design inheritance from abstract class which is not initiated but seemingly must be initiated?

Tags: java, design, inheritance, abstract-class

I need to design a program in Java which calculates arithmetic expressions (only addition or subtraction).

> Requirements:
>
> 1) abstract class `Expression` which contains abstract method `calculate()` and method `equals()` which overrides `Object`.
>
> 2) concrete class `AtomicExpression` which inherits from `Expression` and must have a constructor which receives a real number. This class represents a single number.
>
> 3) abstract class `CompoundExpression` which inherits from `Expression` and has a constructor which receives 2 `Expression` objects (two operands). This class represents an arithmetic expression with 2 operands.
>
> 4) concrete classes`AdditionExpression` and `SubtractionExpression` whose constructors also receive 2 `Expression` objects. These classes actually calculate the expressions with 2 operands.

My natural instinct was to add a `result` instance field and constructor to `Expression` which would store the result of an expression. If it's atomic expression then the result would be the number itself. If we're dealing with a compound expression then we'll store the result of the expression in `result`. But then `CompoundExpression` also inherits from `Expression` as well as **receives** 2 `Expression` objects in its own constructor. So `CompoundExpression` can't really initialize its parent (`Expression` has one field, `CompoundExpression` receives **two** parameters).

If I were to forgo a constructor in `Expression` then I can't really override `equals` in `Expression` because I need to be able to make comparison based on some field.

How can I solve this conundrum?

Comment: Please just follow the requirements exactly. There is no need for fields other than those that are required to persist the arguments passed to the constructors. There is especially no `result` since the `Expression` type is supposed to calculate its result only when calling `calculate()`.

Comment: ok so how can I override `equals` from `Expression`? what will my `equals` compare?

Comment: When is `expr1` equal to `expr2`? This is maths: e.g. `4 + 2` is equal to `3 + 3`. So two expressions are apparently equal when their calculation results in the same result?

Comment: Seems like it's not defined in the requirment, so we can't tell.

Comment: @poke I think I understand now: we can implement `equals()` using `calculate()`. and `AdditionExpression` will receive 2 `AtomicExpression` objects, right?

Comment: `AdditionExpression` will just receive two `Expression` objects, yes. The point of the compound expressions is that they can take any kind of expression. So doing something like `2 + ((3 + 4) + (7 - 2))` is easily possible (it would be `Add(Atomic(2), Add(Add(Atomic(3), Atomic(4)), Subtract(Atomic(7), Atomic(2))))`)

Comment: @Yos: Is there a reason to assume that the default `equals` implementation is insufficient here? By default, `equals` will consider every `Expression` object as distinct from all others.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau do you mean using `equals` from `Object` and comparing by addresses? What is the "default equals"?

Comment: @Yos: Yes. That is the "default equals", because that is the behaviour you get unless you explicitly override `Object.equals`.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau we want to compare expressions by their result value not by addresses.

Comment: You don't have to use the language's `equals()` to compare expressions, you can define you own domain specific (and correct for the domain) definition of comparison.  So, some comparison methods could simply be abstract -- let the subclasses implement that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with what we might call an [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

The purpose of the tree is to capture an expression.  There are other ways to capture expressions, such as text.  A text form is a [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).  In some serializations of expressions (e.g. [infix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation)), we need to use parenthesis — ()'s — to override [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations); however, in an AST, the operator precedence is explicit in the shape of the tree, so no parenthesis are necessary.

We capture expressions as trees for a variety of reasons.  In compiler technology, expressions are often represented as trees at some point in the translation process (e.g. [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) output).  The compiler's task is to translate the expression into a form (usually lower level, like byte-code or machine code)  for later execution (or further translation for later execution).

Such a tree might also be evaluated instead of translated; this might occur, for example, in an interpreter.  In an interpreter, usually evaluation of such an expression tree would happen after the construction of the tree; this is because the interpreter may choose to analyze the expression (tree) before evaluation, and/or, because the interpreter wants to be able to evaluate the expression more than once — each time with possibly different values for variables, so the same expression can yield a different final result if variables are updated.

In your case as there are no variables (only constants), there is no (obvious) advantage to delaying execution — so you ***might be tempted*** to consider doing execution as part of construction.  This would imply having a result or value for all entities before construction, and so you might provide, in the abstract base class, a constructor that receives the value, and a field that holds the value; however, as you note, that would require that the `CompoundExpression` and `AdditionExpression` also construct in terms of values, and this would be a different assignment.

***By the text of your requirements, (1) you must provide a `calculate()` method for (post-construction) evaluation of the expression, and (2) you must provide a constructor for `AdditionExpression` that takes two `Expression`s and no values!!***

Your job is to support tree construction for later evaluation, not to build a tree while simultaneously computing its final value.  So, separate those concepts in your mind — construction of the tree from evaluation of the tree.  Evaluation will be done post construction.

> If I were to forgo a constructor in Expression then I can't really override equals in Expression because I need to be able to make comparison based on some field.

To repeat myself, you are conflating construction with evaluation.  In the model of those requirements, construction happens first, and evaluation is delayed until construction is completed.

The override for `equals(...)` will execute only in the post-construction environment.  No one will call `equals` during construction of the tree, eh?

Thus, in your `equals` override you can assume that trees are fully constructed!  Fully constructed trees support the interface provided by the abstract class `Expression` — they can be evaluated to obtain their value!